# Numpy TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars (reshape)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In Python, if I reshape an array, I have no problem in general:

```
arr1 = np.array([1,2,3,4])
print np.reshape(arr1, (2, 2, 1))
```

But I have a problem when I try to reshape a 10240 x 62 numpy ndarray:

```
a1 = np.reshape(X_train_s, (X_train_s[0], X_train_s[1], 1))
```

The error is:

```
...in reshape
    return reshape(newshape, order=order)
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

The ndarray X_train_s contains float32 numbers. Why can't I reshape the array?

Comment: `X_train_s[0]` is not 10240, and `X_train_s[1]` is not 62. Those are the first and second entire rows of your array. If you wanted 10240 and 62, you should be indexing `X_train_s.shape`.

Comment: `X_train[0]` returns an array. A "row" of your 10240x62 array. The shape argument only accepts scalars, and as the error message indicates, an array of length greater than 1 cannot be implicitely converted to a scalar.

Comment: This is just a guess, but you seem to be missing two `.shape` in your second codeblock.

Comment: Oh my....Thank you @user2357112

Comment: @user2357112 If you write that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wanted the lengths of the first and second dimensions of `X_train_s`, but when you did

```
(X_train_s[0], X_train_s[1], 1)
```

you took the first and second *entire rows*, not the lengths of the first and second dimensions. If you wanted to access dimension lengths, you should have indexed the array's `shape`:

```
(X_train_s.shape[0], X_train_s.shape[1], 1)
```

You might also want to consider other ways of adding this extra length-1 axis to the array, such as indexing with `np.newaxis` (a.k.a. `None`):

```
a1 = X_train_s[:, :, np.newaxis]
```