# "TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars" when compiling LSTM neural network

Tags: python, numpy, keras, neural-network, lstm

I am currently making an LSTM neural network to analyze the closing prices of stock data. I am getting an error which reads:

`TypeError: Error converting shape to a TensorShape: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.`

when executing this code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
#take user input to replace stock to analyze
userInput = input('Stocks: \n')
days = int(input('how many time series to analyze? \n'))
#read data
data = pd.read_csv('Stocks/%s.us.txt' % userInput, usecols=[5], engine = 'python', skipfooter = 3)
#convert it into numpy array
dataSet = data.values
#scale the data into a range of 0, 1
scaling = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0,1))
#transform testing data to have 0 mean
dataSet = scaling.fit_transform(dataSet)
#splitting to testing and training data
trainData = int(len(dataSet) * 0.80)
testData = len(dataSet) - trainData
#time series data shaping
features = []  
labels = []  
for i in range(days, len(dataSet)):  
    features.append(dataSet[i-days:i, 0])
    labels.append(dataSet[i, 0])
#convert features and labels to numpy arrays
features, labels = np.array(features), np.array(labels)
#building LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(1, dataSet)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse')
model.fit(trainData, testData, batch_size = 32, epochs = 10)
```

---

In this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281481/numpy-typeerror-only-length-1-arrays-can-be-converted-to-python-scalars-reshap) it explains that this problem might arise from indexing the rows of the different dimensions rather than the lengths, but I do not see how this applies to my code, as I never index anything of that sort. I have tried looking in other posts but none of the solutions apply to my problem. **It is also worth noting that the error traces back to line 143 of an Anaconda3 lib file, like so**

```
File "C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 143, in make_shape
```

---

Why is this error showing up, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Which line of your code?  Most likely you are passing a parameter that should be a single number, but is a multivalue Tensorflow object.

Comment: This line looks suspect: `model.add(LSTM(1, input_shape=(1, dataSet)))`.  What is `dataSet`?  Elsewhere you use `len(dataSet)`, suggesting it is an iterable (list, array, tensorflow).  `(1, dataSet)` wouldn't be a valid `shape`.

Comment: Thank you! That was precisely the problem. I fixed it by changing that from `(1, dataSet)` to `(1, len(dataSet))`